# Why is this leaking memory? (Pointer Array C)

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, valgrind

Gmorning SO-

valgrind says:

```
==9735== 24,976 bytes in 446 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 9 of 9
==9735==    at 0x100012362: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==9735==    by 0x1000016F2: interpolate (in ./a.out)
==9735==    by 0x100000CFA: main (in ./a.out)
```

Yikes. Here's my interpolate function:

```
void interpolate(PDouble* evaluated, int doubleCount){
int i, j, k;
int boxCount = 0;
int frameCount = 0;

for(i=0; i<doubleCount; i++){
  boxCount = evaluated[i]->first->numBoxes;
  frameCount = evaluated[i]->gap;
  evaluated[i]->changeMatrix = (int***)malloc(boxCount*sizeof(int**));

for(j=0; j < boxCount; j++){
  evaluated[i]->changeMatrix[j] = (int **)malloc(ATTR * sizeof(int*));

  for(k=0; k < ATTR; k++){
    evaluated[i]->changeMatrix[j][k] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*frameCount);
    if(evaluated[i]->differenceMatrix[j][k] > 200 ||
       evaluated[i]->differenceMatrix[j][k] < -200){
      generateRotationSequence(evaluated[i]->changeMatrix[j][k],
                               evaluated[i]->first->boxes[j]->o,
                               evaluated[i]->second->boxes[j]->o,
                               frameCount);
    }
    else{
      evaluated[i]->changeMatrix[j][k] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*frameCount);
      generateSequence(evaluated[i]->changeMatrix[j][k], 
                       evaluated[i]->differenceMatrix[j][k], frameCount);
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

But I have the C functions that free all the pointers for PDoubles. I can provide the code if needed, but is there anything glaring about this that would make it leak, or make pointers dangle?

Edit: Realized I was using a strange term in description. Also this time im adding my destructors

```
void killDouble(PDouble marked){
int i, j, k;
int gap = marked->gap;
for(i=0; i < marked->first->numBoxes; i++){
  for(j=0; j < ATTR; j++){
    free(marked->changeMatrix[i][j]);
  }
  free(marked->changeMatrix[i]);
  free(marked->differenceMatrix[i]);
}
for(i=0; i < gap; i++){
  killFrame(marked->intFrames[i]);
}
killFrame(marked->first);
killFrame(marked->second);
free(marked->changeMatrix);
free(marked->differenceMatrix);
free(marked->intFrames);
free(marked);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You allocate `evaluated[i]->changeMatrix[j][k]`

```
evaluated[i]->changeMatrix[j][k] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*frameCount);
if(evaluated[i]->differenceMatrix[j][k] > 200 ||
   evaluated[i]->differenceMatrix[j][k] < -200){
  generateRotationSequence(evaluated[i]->changeMatrix[j][k],
                           evaluated[i]->first->boxes[j]->o,
                           evaluated[i]->second->boxes[j]->o,
                           frameCount);
}
else{
  evaluated[i]->changeMatrix[j][k] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*frameCount);
```

unconditionally and then again without freeing if the condition is not satisfied. That's your leak.

Since both allocations are exactly the same, you should remove the one in the `else` block, it is pointless.

Comment: Sorry I think I was leaving off something critical. I just added the function I call later on every "PDouble" in the program. Wouldn't that free it?

Comment: No, when you call it, the pointer obtained from the first allocation is already lost. Since the allocation is exactly the same as the one before the `if`, remove it. Or just put a `free(evaluated[i]->changeMatrix[j][k]);` at the start of the `else` block.

Comment: Got it. Didn't even realize I was mallocing it out twice. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
evaluated[i]->changeMatrix[j][k] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*frameCount);
```

This is the leak. You allocate memory, but never free